# Overriding equals method for Arrays.BinarySearch

Tags: java, equals, binary-search

I have a class which `implements comparable` to compare and sort an array of its instances on the basis of one of the class variables. Now I want to be able to search the array of this class objects using `Arrays.binarySearch`. For that, will overiding the `equals` method be enough?

Comment: I understand that the question has already got good answers but I am a bit curious to know what you mean by " compare and sort an array of its instances on the basis of one of the class variables". So you have a class which implements Comparable and holds an array of its own type and compares each element in this array on the basis of another member of itself?

Comment: @bot: say in my class I have an instance field of type int. Now I wish that Arrays.sort(myClassArray) would sort myClassArray the same way had myClassArray been an int Array with each int instance being equal to the corresponding int type instance field in MyClass.

Comment: Makes sense now. It was unclear whether the instance variable which was going to be used in the compare method was a primitive or not. Thus my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `binarySearch` works on "more or less" comparisons rather than equality comparisons. If you're implementing `Comparable` properly, such that it obeys the interface consistently, in particular returning 0 when items are equal, that should be all that's required. (Alternatively, you can specify a `Comparator`.)

Of course, the array has to be ordered appropriately before `binarySearch` will work...

Comment: Using `Comparable` instead of `equals` for the search itself is an implementation detail, I gather...? Wouldn't it be safer to override `equals` anyway, just in case you run into different implementations in the future?

Comment: @JoãoMendes: Not really - it's a natural result of this being a binary search, which *has* to be implemented in terms of `compare` rather than `equals`. Overriding `equals` in a consistent way would certainly be sensible, sure... but more for the sake of general consistency rather than for binary searches.

Comment: The JavaDocs are, in my opinion, a bit unclear on this, but note that they reference the "natural ordering" of the elements, and if you click on that link, it takes you to the page for "Comparable". I believe the intent is that this is not an implementation detail but the documented behavior. Partly because of that link, and party because without this assumption, the user would have no way to know how to control the behavior. That said, it is good practice to always implement equals when you implement Comparable and to make them consistent.

Comment: PS It's not sufficient to implement compareTo to return 0 when the two values are equal. It must also return a negative number when the first value is less and a positive number when the first value is greater.

Comment: @Jay: Well yes, you have to actually implement the interface properly.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I just thought that part of your answer might be misleading, someone might think that you were giving a complete description of what they need to implement. Well, I don't want to turn this minor point into a long discussion.

Answer (score 0):

`equals` is not used for sorted operations.  Instead it is assumed that `compareTo == 0` and `equals == true` are one and the same.

Instead you need to implement compareTo to return 0 when they are equal or implement your own Comparator.